# NPM not installing dependencies?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

Having trouble getting NPM to install dependencies with `npm install -d` in my project directory with a defined `package.json` file.

Here's my `package.json`: https://gist.github.com/3068312

And after wiping my project root's node modules folder (`rm -rf node_modules`), I run `npm install -d` in my project root and am greeted with this:

```
(ssh) /vagrant git:master ❯ npm install -d                                                                                                                                                                  
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@1.1.4
npm info using node@v0.6.12
npm info preinstall redeye@0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sinon
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sinon
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm info into /vagrant underscore@1.3.3
npm info into /vagrant mocha@1.3.0
npm info into /vagrant sinon@1.3.4
npm info into /vagrant request@2.9.203
npm info installOne underscore@1.3.3
npm info installOne mocha@1.3.0
npm info installOne sinon@1.3.4
npm info installOne request@2.9.203
npm info unbuild /vagrant/node_modules/underscore
npm info unbuild /vagrant/node_modules/mocha
npm info unbuild /vagrant/node_modules/sinon
npm info unbuild /vagrant/node_modules/request
npm ERR! error installing underscore@1.3.3
npm info unbuild /vagrant/node_modules/underscore
npm ERR! error rolling back underscore@1.3.3 Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/vagrant/node_modules/underscore'

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/vagrant/node_modules/underscore/package.json'
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /vagrant/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-d"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! path /vagrant/node_modules/underscore/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message ENOENT, no such file or directory '/vagrant/node_modules/underscore/package.json'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! error installing request@2.9.203
npm info unbuild /vagrant/node_modules/request
npm ERR! error rolling back request@2.9.203 Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/vagrant/node_modules/request'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vagrant/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

If I rerun `npm install -d`, the error changes to whatever the next package is... if I keep running it it over and over again, it eventually doesn't complain anymore and outputs:

```
(ssh) /vagrant git:master ❯ npm install -d                                                                                                                                                               
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@1.1.4
npm info using node@v0.6.12
npm info preinstall redeye@0.0.1
npm info build /vagrant
npm info linkStuff redeye@0.0.1
npm info install redeye@0.0.1
npm info postinstall redeye@0.0.1
npm info ok
```

However, none of the dependencies for any of these packages get installed. For instance, `cheerio` has a few dependencies, so when I try running my test suite, I'm greeted with:

```
(ssh) /vagrant git:master ❯ mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script --watch spec/*                                                                                                                           


node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'cheerio-select'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
```

What gives? I'm on Ubuntu Precise64 in a [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) virtual box.

Answer (score 1):

maybe Something wrong related to symlink on vagrant and this issue :
https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2380

try

```
npm install --no-bin-link
```

also explained here : http://www.conroyp.com/2013/04/13/symlink-shenanigans-nodejs-npm-express-vagrant/

Comment: While trying Docker Tutorial https://prakhar.me/docker-curriculum/#dockerrun  
getting same error while running root@ip-172-31-22-20:~/docker-curriculum# docker build -t ashishkarpe/foodtrucks-web .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `npm cache clean`?

I was having a hell of a time trying to install the dependencies for Qunit the other day and it was due to phantonjs failing to build on the first run, but when I went to reinstall, npm wasn't refetching the binaries and just trying to build from the cached ones. After emptying the cache and rerunning `npm install` it refetched them and was successfully built.